# Where is 'initializeApp' in firebase imports?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I started taking a look into firebase and just after defining the intialization as

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat"

const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
   authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
   projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
   storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
   messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
   appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID,
   measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

const chatSupportApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, "my-app");
```

A wild warning was display!

```
/*It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import
the individual SDK components you intend to use.

For the module builds, these are available in the following manner
(replace <PACKAGE> with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database, etc):

CommonJS Modules:
const firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/<PACKAGE>');

ES Modules:
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/<PACKAGE>';

Typescript:
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/<PACKAGE>';*/
```

I search in many posts, including documentation and didn't really get how to initialize my app first before using any of the other imports

I found out lately that is was a bit hidden under **"firebase/firebase-app"**

so it get solved, as

```
import {initializeApp} from "firebase/firebase-app";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: ...............
};

const chatSupportApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig, "my-app");

export default chatSupportApp;
```

This started as a question that I search in most stack overflow posts, but since I solve it for now somehow I wanted also to share with the community in here, but also consider any other suggestion, the question will be then.

Is this approach correct? why all the documentation suggest to do it with

**import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';** as:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, getRedirectResult } from 'firebase/auth';
```

This really didn't work for me at all and I was not able to use it.

Thanks and enjoy your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import {initializeApp} from "firebase/firebase-app";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: ...............
};

const chatSupportApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig, "my-app");

export default chatSupportApp;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).